# Flutter sdk errors

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I tried downloading the latest version of Flutter SDK and it made errors in the code and got worse. this is the error:

```
/C:/fluttersdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_place_picker-1.0.1/lib/src/components/prediction_tile.dart:29:51: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/fluttersdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
    final textColor = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color;
                                                  ^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\fluttersdk\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\fluttersdk\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed

```
Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color
```

and added `Colors.black`

```
final textColor = Colors.black;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your package [google_maps_place_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_place_picker) is deprecated. Update it and try again.

Comment: google_maps_place_picker is on its latest version i've upgraded all the packges

Comment: have you used this version:- 2.1.0-nullsafety.3

Comment: no i am using google_maps_place_picker: ^1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to run pub upgrade then run these commands:

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get
```

Comment: it didn't work still with the same error